# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_server_msg', Socketio (chat with Django)

Tags: django, sockets, websocket

I'm new with django and I try to implement a chat, using socketio. I used ://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio and I followed this tutorial: http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/

The example works well. Now I would like to integrate this chat inside the templates of my django app. I didn't find any tutorial about that.

So I tried to take the example, I put the html inside my template and I used the .py inside my view.

So here is the part of my views.py that is creating the problem:

```
buffer = []
socketio = request.environ['socketio']
if socketio.on_connect():
    socketio.send({'buffer': buffer})
    socketio.broadcast({'announcement': socketio.session.session_id + ' connected'})

while True:
    message = socketio.recv()

    if len(message) == 1:
        message = message[0]
        message = {'message': [socketio.session.session_id, message]}
        buffer.append(message)
        if len(buffer) > 15:
            del buffer[0]
        socketio.broadcast(message)
    else:
        if not socketio.connected():
            socketio.broadcast({'announcement': socketio.session.session_id + '  disconnected'})
            break
```

But when I go to my page I get this error message:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_server_msg'

```
   Exception Type:  AttributeError
   Exception Value:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_server_msg'
   Exception Location:  /Users/marc-antoinelacroix/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site- packages/socketio/protocol.py in recv, line 41
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix that?
Thank you,